# Getting error, Spring BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validateableConstraintsEvaluator'

Tags: grails3

I have updated my project from `grails2.5.6` to `grails3.3.9` and successfully completed unit testing.
While running the integration test I am getting the following Exception.

```
2019-03-07 18:26:12.169  WARN --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.spockframework.spring.SpringMockTestExecutionListener@157b7da6] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void com.mdw360.sec.UserControllerSpec.$spock_feature_0_1()] for test instance [com.mdw360.sec.UserControllerSpec@36f464d8]

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validateableConstraintsEvaluator': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1646)
```

**Controller**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class UserController {

    def userCache
    def springSecurityService
    def utilityService

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]


    def create() {
        List<Role> roles = Role.list()
        Map roleMap = [:]
        roles.each { role -> roleMap[role] = false }
        render view: 'create', model: [userCO: new SaveUserCO(), roleMap: roleMap]
    }

......
......
}
```

**TestClass**

```
import grails.gorm.transactions.Rollback
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
@Rollback
class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    UserController controller
}

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test create render correct view and model when no role exists"() {
        when:
        controller.request.method='POST'
        controller.create()

        then:
        assert controller.modelAndView.viewName == '/user/create'
        assert controller.modelAndView.model.size() == 2
        assert controller.modelAndView.model.roleMap.size() == 0
        assert controller.modelAndView.model.userCO != null
    }

    void "test create render correct view and model when role exists"() {
        when:
        controller.request.method='POST'
        createRole('ROLE_TEST')
        controller.create()

        then:
        assert controller.modelAndView.viewName == '/user/create'
        assert controller.modelAndView.model.size() == 2
        assert controller.modelAndView.model.roleMap.size() == 1
        assert controller.modelAndView.model.userCO != null
    }
...
....
}
```

I am using Grails 3.3.9 with JDK 1.8, gormVersion 6.1.11 and 
gradle3.5

Answer (score 0):

I my case I have a folder called `acceptance-test` where I had some integration test I wanted to execute. I created a `acceptanceTest` gradle task similar to this one [integration-test.gradle](https://github.com/biasedbit/gradle-plugins/blob/master/integration-test.gradle).

If the task `acceptanceTest` was executed, the BeanCreationException was thrown. I had to manually active the spring profile `dev`

```
./gradlew acceptanceTest -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

The root problem is that some grails global variables (like `grailsApplication`, `messageSource`) are not created and are need to run test. To run integration test these global variables must be created or mocked by Grails. Setting `spring.profile.active` to `test` creates all these global variables.